# Elasticsearch phrase/ multi-worlds search

Tags: php, elasticsearch, search

I am trying to implement a use case wherein a user can make a multi-words/ phrase search for 'product_name' field.

Assuming someone is searching for 'Richest Man', the following results should come:

- The Richest Man in Babylon
- Story of the Richest man
- The richest man in the world
- How to win the richest man

Search result must not include the following docs-

- Richest woman and man
- When a poor man becomes the richest

Here is the analyser that I wrote:

```
'settings' => [
    'analysis' => [
        'filter' => [
            'autocomplete_filter' => ['type' => 'ngram', 'min_gram' => 1, 'max_gram' => 10]
        ],
        'analyzer' => [
            'autocomplete' => ['type' => 'custom', 'tokenizer' => 'standard', 'filter' => ['lowercase', 'autocomplete_filter']]
        ]
    ],
    'index.max_ngram_diff' => 10
],
'mappings' => ['properties' => [
    'product_name' => ['type' => 'text', 'analyzer' => 'autocomplete', 'search_analyzer', 'standard'],                  
]],
```

and I am using the following code, written in PHP to make a search request:

```
$params = [
    'index' => ProductData::ELASTIC_INDEX,
    'type' => ProductData::ELASTIC_TYPE,
    'body' => [
        'query' => ['match' => ['product_name' => ['query' => $requestVars['product_name']]]
    ],
    ]
];

$result =  $this->client->search($params);
```

However, the result that I am getting is unexpected and not the ones that I listed above.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined the `autocomplete` analyzer, that has an n-gram tokenizer in it, so the tokens generated for `"When a poor man becomes the richest"` will include `"when"`, `"a"`, `"poor"`, `"man"`, `"becomes"`, `"the"`, `"richest"`.

Now when you will search for `Richest Man`, this will return all the matching documents that have `richest` or `man` in their document

Instead of defining any separate analyzer, you can simply use the [match_phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html)

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "name": "Richest Man"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result will be**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67784465",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.15394104,
        "_source": {
          "name": "The Richest Man in Babylon"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67784465",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.15394104,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Story of the Richest man"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67784465",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.14290144,
        "_source": {
          "name": "The richest man in the world"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67784465",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.14290144,
        "_source": {
          "name": "How to win the richest man"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks @ESCoder. This solves the original issue that I had posted. I should have provided a bit more details. If I search for "richest m" or "hest man" I should get those  4 results. If I search for "richest", "ches" or "ma" I should be seeing all the results i.e. 6 documents.